# Does the Create Water spell need to be cast on a vessel that would be filled by it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The Create Water spells reads:

> In an open container, you can create up to 10 gallons of drinkable
>   water. You may also produce a rain that falls within a 30-foot cube
>   and extinguishes open-air flames.

**Must the container be filled by the water created?**  IE, a horse trough or sinkhole would not be valid targets, since they can hold more than 10 gallons of water?

**If not; what prevents me from simply choosing the room I'm in as the container?**  For example, creating 10 gallons worth of water on the floor with the intent of freezing it to make ice terrain?

Or further, choosing the room and creating a gush of water over an unruly bar patron to "cool them off" - I can create rain, does something restrict me to Creating Water on or very close to a surface?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Also, the wording in your quote doesn't match the spell description; I'm guessing it's taken from an unofficial wiki that intentionally rewords stuff in a futile attempt to avoid WotC's wrath. Here's the relevant part of the official description of the [*create or destroy water*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-or-destroy-water) spell: "**Create Water.** You create up to 10 gallons of clean water within range in an open container. Alternatively, the water falls as rain in a 30-foot cube within range, extinguishing exposed flames in the area."

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer to your question may lie within the spell's written affect, *You can create* **up to** *10 gallons of drinkable water.*

There is nothing that specifically states it must fill the container, but something that **does** state you can create up to 10 gallons of water (as in you can create between 0 and 10 gallons of water). So long as it can be an area with an open space, you should be able to create water inside of it.

*Note:* the GM has final say, given they have more power than the gods in their universe.

Answer (score 1):

**Must the container be filled by the water created?**

No.  The relevant portion of the [*create or destroy water*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-or-destroy-water) spell description states (PHB 229):

> You create up to 10 gallons of clean water within range in an open container.

There is no mention of the need to fill the container.

**If not; what prevents me from simply choosing the room I'm in as the container?**

Simply that a room is not a container.  A room is a room, and a container is a container.  There's no reason why the word container would mean room in this case.  If you want water in a room use the rain feature of this spell.

D&D 5e generally uses words to mean what they mean in everyday English unless otherwise stated.  [Here is a tweet from Jeremy Crawford, lead rules designer of D&D, to support this](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/793506314148163584):

> Unless the rules explicitly expand, narrow, or completely redefine a word, that word retains the meaning it has in idiomatic English. #DnD

**I can create rain, does something restrict me to Creating Water on or very close to a surface?**

Yes, the text of the spell description clearly states, "in an open container."  This means you can create the water in an open container.  Why?  It's D&D, that's how the magic works.

All that being said it would not break the game to expand this first level spell a bit and allow water on the floor of a room.  Of course, your GM would have to approve this usage, as it is not allowed by RAW.